# Go: передача указателей в метод и их изменение

Tags: golang, указатели

Начал изучать Go, но что-то не могу разобраться с сабжем. Вот есть linked list

```
    type List struct {
        next *List
        val  any
}
```

создаю его экземпляр вот так

```
myList := &List{nil, 1}
```

добавляю ещё звеньев и пытаюсь его развернуть вот так

```
func (n *List) Reverse() {
    var tmp *List
    tmp = n
    var prev *List
    var last *List
    for tmp != nil {
        last = tmp.next
        tmp.next = prev
        prev = tmp
        tmp = last
    }
    *n = *prev
}
```

сам разворот стандартный, взят из другого языка, где работает.
Но тут список странным образом зацикливается.
Что я делаю не так?
Такой список `1 2 3 4`  превращается в `4 3 2 4 3 2 4 3 2 4 3 2 4 3 2 4 3 2 4`

Вот ссылка на код https://go.dev/play/p/VLffKqlex-d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы берёте первый элемент списка в выражении `tmp = n`, вы записываете в `tmp` указатель на ту же ячейку памяти, куда указывает `n`.

Соответственно, когда вы при обращении строите второй элемент, его указатель `.next` указывает на `n`

Когда после цикла вы делаете `*n = *prev` происходит вот что: по адресу `n` изменяются значения полей `n->next` и `n->val`, но само значение `n` не изменяется. Это означает, что препоследний элемент обращённого списка будет указывать на голову списка. Получается цикл.

Для того, чтобы цикл не возникал, нужно, чтобы при обращении последний элемент был в новом месте. Вместо `tmp = n` напишите `tmp = &List{n.next, n.val}`

Собственно, ваш `Push` работает именно благодаря тому, что вы присваиванием `last := *n` создаёте копию головы списка в новом месте в куче. В результате после присваивания `*n = *node` в ячейке `n.next` лежит указатель на свежеаллоцированный `last`

Пример работающего кода https://go.dev/play/p/LiWA4NfpV82

ДОБАВКА

Как обратить список без создания нового узла. Вместо того, чтобы просто копировать `n` содержимое головы обращённого списка, нужно обменять содержимое этих пар. И обновить указатель в предпоследнем элементе:

```
type List struct {
    next *List
    val  interface{}
}

func (l *List) ReverseInPlace() {
    if l == nil {
        // empty list
        return
    }
    var head, tail *List
    var second_last *List
    tail = l
    for tail != nil {
        next_tail := tail.next
        tail.next = head
        head = tail
        tail = next_tail

        if head.next == l {
            second_last = head
        }
    }
    // Swap l.val and head.val
    if l == head {
        // single-element list
        // do nothing
    } else {
        *l, *head = *head, *l
        // Update last-but-one element
        if second_last == head {
            // two element list
            l.next = head
        } else {
            // more than 2 elements in the list
            second_last.next = head
        }
    }
}
```

Полный код https://go.dev/play/p/GCNLeGWxezi
ВНИМАНИЕ: этот пример не проверяет наличие цикла в списке.

Comment: Спасибо. Тоже пришёл к созданию промежуточного звена. Кажется, я слегка запутался, где у меня звенья, а где – указатели на них. Go еще и позволяет использовать одни как другие, так что надо повысить внимательность ) Но вообще должен быть способ разворота без создания временного звена, и без головы списка. Как мне кажется )

Comment: @Сергей конечно можно обойтись без временного звена. Для этого достаточно переставить местами содержимое головы списка, ставшей последним элементом обращенного списка, и ячейки tmp, которая стала головой обращенного списка. Ну и поменять указатель в предпоследнем элементе: https://go.dev/play/p/GCNLeGWxezi

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо, вроде разобрался. По классике нам нужно менять в методе значение myList (который является указателем на голову листа), но ресивер у нас *List, поэтому изменить мы можем только эту самую голову, но не указатель. Чтобы менять собственно указатель, метод должен выглядеть как `func (l **List) Reverse()`, но Go так не позволяет(?), потому что `A receiver base type cannot be a pointer`. То есть передать в метод **указатель** для изменения не выйдет. Правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Да, действительно это так работать не будет. Ну, по крайней мере, у меня тоже не получилось. Я думаю, что адрес ресивера нельзя менять на прямую и нельзя сделать так:

```
func (l **List) Reverse()
```

но можно сделать так:

```
func Reverse(list **List) {
    node := *list
    var prev *List

    for node != nil {
        node, prev, node.next = node.next, node, prev
    }
    *list = prev
}
```

что выглядит не красиво, а может и идиоматически не правильно. Тогда можно хранит указатель на голову списка в отдельной переменной структуры как сделано в этом примере:
https://gist.github.com/P-A-R-U-S/55ee88bfecb87f8614e1a4f67b57c866

Comment: Спасибо. Про голову знаю, но у меня задача не сделать список, а разобраться с языком. Загвоздка именно в изменении ресивера, т.к. вот таким образом всё работает `func (n *List) Reverse() *List {
... return prev
}`

Comment: Интересно, что функция Push отлично работает ```func (n *List) Push(a any) {
  last := *n
  node := &List{next: &last, val: a}
  *n = *node
}```